# spark rest api /api/v1 gives method not allowed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have deployed a spark standalone cluster, but when i try to access the rest api for some application info. The url i try to access is http://ip:4040/api/v1.

Link for the rest api doc -> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

It says

> METHOD NOT ALLOWED

I think this is some config issue or something.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url `http://ip:4040/api/v1` is just the common path for all endpoinds. You are getting this because you are calling `GET` method but its not allowed.

If you need to get list of applications use `http://ip:4040/api/v1/applications` instead.

Here is [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cb87b3ced9453b5717fa8e8637b97a2f3f25fdd7/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/ApiRootResource.scala) if you are interested in.